# JSF 2.2: Not able to select input text box after closing the p:dialog modal dialog in Mozilla FireFox

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

Environment

- Java 1.8
- JSF 2.2
- WLP_16_0_0_3
- Mozilla FireFox 52.0.1 (64-bit).

We are using  modal dialog while navigating from one page to another page.

**This is a simple test case scenario:**

*1.commonInclude.xhtml*
This is a commonInclude xhtml. It is having code for a p:dialog modal.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
[<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">]>

<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui">

<f:view locale="#{localeBean.locale}" contentType="text/html" encoding="ISO-8859-1">    
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>                          
        <title>
            <ui:insert name="title">Default Title</ui:insert>
        </title>            
        <h:outputStylesheet name="components.css" library="primefaces" />
        <h:outputScript name="jquery/jquery.js" library="primefaces"/>
        <h:outputScript name="jquery/jquery-plugins.js" library="primefaces"/>          
        <h:outputScript name="core.js" library="primefaces"/>
        <h:outputScript name="components.js" library="primefaces"/> 
    </h:head>

    <ui:insert name="metadata"/>

   <h:body id="entirePageBody" style="margin:auto;margin-top:0;text-align:center;">
        <p:dialog widgetVar="ajax_status_dialog" modal="true" draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false" showHeader="false">           
          <h:outputText value="This is a Modal Dialog." />
        </p:dialog>         
        <p:ajaxStatus id="ajaxStatusPanel" onstart="PF('ajax_status_dialog').show()" oncomplete="PF('ajax_status_dialog').hide();" /> 
    </h:body>
</f:view>
```

*2. Page1.xhtml* 
- This First Page. It is having 'Next' command button

```
    <!DOCTYPE html [<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">]>
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" 
        xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core" 
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions" xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui" xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf" 
        template="/WEB-INF/faces/template/commonInclude.xhtml">

    <ui:param name="_pageTitle" value="sampleFirstPage"/>   
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id=firstpageform" prependId="false">
            <c:set var="testController" value="#{testController}" scope="request"/>
            <c:set var="controllerBean" value="#{testController.controllerBean}" scope="request"/>
            <p:messages closable="true" escape="false"/>
            <h:panelGroup layout="block"><h:outputText value="My First Page"/></h:panelGroup>           
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <p:panelGrid>
                <p:row>
                    <p:column><h:outputText value="Welcome to First Page"/>. </p:column>
                </p:row>
            </p:panelGrid>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <p:panelGrid styleClass="button">
                <p:row>                 
                    <p:column>
                        <p:commandButton value="Next" action="#{testController.nextCont}" update="@form" id="method"/>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
            </p:panelGrid>
            <at:validateBean value="#{testController.controllerBean}"/>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

When click 'Next' button,

1. It displays 'dialog modal' as implemented in 'commonInclude.xhtml
2. Then page2.xhtml. will be displayed.

Here: *page2.xhtml* is having input text field as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html [<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">]>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core" 
xmlns:fn="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/functions" xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions" xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui" xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf" 
template="/WEB-INF/faces/template/commonInclude.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="_pageTitle" value="Second Page"/>
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="secondpageform" prependId="false">
            <c:set var="testController" value="#{testController}" scope="request"/>
            <c:set var="controllerBean" value="#{testController.controllerBean}" scope="request"/>
            <p:messages closable="true" escape="false"/>
            <h:panelGroup layout="block"><h:outputText value="Second Page"/></h:panelGroup>         
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <p:panelGrid>
                <p:row>             
                    <p:column>
                        <p:inputText value="#{controllerBean.newNumber}" id="controllerBean_-newNumber" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
            </p:panelGrid>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <p:panelGrid>
                <p:row>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:commandButton type="button" value="Next" id="next"/>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
            </p:panelGrid>
            <at:validateBean value="#{testController.controllerBean}"/>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Issue:

- I am not able to click,select or edit this input field.
- If I remove the modal dialog code, Then it is working fine and I am able to click,select or edit this input field.

This issue is happening only in Mozilla Firefox browser.

Comment: Where are your forms?

Comment: Afaik prependId="false" is a reminiscence from JSF 1 and should not be used. But you're showing much too much code than I'd like to replicate to check if it has anything to say. A [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would make it much easier to try to help